# is it possible to fire an event when d3js is ready?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

currently i am adding all javascript files at HTML `<head>` after uglying & using these jquery functions to check document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {}); OR $(function() {});
```

is it possible to fire an event when d3js is ready ? (like cordova `deviceReady`)

i want to remove jquery, currently i depending only the above two jquery function also event firing will help initialising dataset in multiple file

Comment: Are you looking to fire custom events? Have a look here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 3):

Of course, You can do it with this snippet.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
   /* Your D3.js here */
  });
```

Or you can simply put all your JS code in the bottom of your `body` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use `load` event. Something like that would work:

```js
var script= document.createElement('script'),
    loadHandler = function () {
        // code to be executed after script is loaded
    };
script.src = '/d3.js'; // path to script
script.addEventListener('load', loadHandler);
document.head.appendChild(script);
```